# Precision loss when performing large number operation in mysql

Tags: mysql

In MySQL 5.7, a table defined as following shown

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `person_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`),
  KEY `ix_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8
```

And then we prepared two records for testing, the value of `name` field (with varchar type) are

- 123456789123456789
- 1

respectively.

**Case 1**

```
select * from person where name = 123456789123456789-1;
```

Note that we are using a number instead of string inside the where clause. The record with name `123456789123456789` returned, and it seemed that `-1` in the end are ignored!

Furthermore, we add another record with name = `123456789123456788`, and this time the above select returns two records, including both `123456789123456789` and `123456789123456788`;

The output looks so strange!

**Case 2**

```
select * from person where name = 123456789123456789-123456789123456788;
```

We could get the record with name `1`, and in this case it seems that the `-` act as a minus operator.

Why the behavior of `-` in two cases are so different!

Comment: demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff6731/2

Comment: @Jacky, you are hacker :)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = CAST(123456789123456789 - 1 AS CHAR);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't immediately tell you what the type of `123456789123456789-1` is but for the comparison operation, we're almost certainly falling through most of the more "normal" [data type conversion rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) for mysql and ending up at:

> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

Because one of the argument for the comparison (`name`) is a string type and the other is numeric, nothing else matches. So both get converted to floats and float types don't have too many digits of precision. Certainly less than the 18 required to represent 123456789123456789 and 123456789123456788 as two *different* numbers.

Comment: And the reason the second case works is that `123456789123456789-123456789123456788` is computed using integer arithmetic **before** being converted to a float (which is exactly == 1)

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
SELECT person_id, name, name + 0.0, 123456789123456789-1 + 0.0,  name = 123456789123456789-1
FROM person
ORDER BY person_id;
```

Perhaps, before comparing `name = 123456789123456789-1` MySQL converts `name` and `123456789123456789-1` to `DOUBLE` as I showed in select. So some digits are lost.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c003d12/5).

Comment: Nope, for the comparison, the string is converted to a float, not an int.

Comment: Edited the answer, @Damien_The_Unbeliever answer is more exact.